# Comparison of Complexity of counting bits in a binary representation

Tags: time-complexity

I was asked the following question:
Given a number `num` - write a function (in python) that counts the number of ones in its binary representation.
This is the answer i provided

```
def count_bits(num):
    res = 0
    while num > 0:
        res += num & 1
        num = num >> 1
    return res
```

When asked about the complexity - i answered `O(n)` where `n` is the number of bits in the binary representation of `num`. I was told there is another way to implement this to reduce runtime complexity. After a "hint" i have implemented it the following way

```
def count_bits(num):
    res = 0
    while num > 0:
        res += 1 
        num = num & (num - 1)
    return res
```

but isn't this "at least not better" because of the subtraction operation?
from this wikipedia article on [complexity of arithmetic operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations) the subtraction is `O(n)` on 2 numbers with `n` bits.
Is there a difference in time complexity between the algorithms?
Which one is faster? (in theory and in practice)

Comment: Also the `&` operator will need $O(n)$ time.

Comment: It depends on your model of computation, and on whether the input is “large” or not. In the RAM model, arithmetic on machine words takes constant time.

Comment: *Which one is faster in practice?* Try them out!

Comment: @YuvalFilmus - already did and it depends. for numbers with a lot of 0s in their binary representation (`2^i` where `0<i<10000`) - the second approach is faster and for numbers with a lot of 1s in their binary representation (`2^i-1` where `0<i<10000`)  it seems that the first approach performs better.

Comment: Now you need to decide whether you are interested in *worst case* complexity, *average case* complexity, or something else. If you are interested in average case complexity, you need to decide on a distribution with respect to which you take the average. Then you can repeat the experiments, with your chosen form of time complexity in mind. (If you chose worst-case and the numbers are very large, you might need to figure out first what inputs are the worst.)